# Regex to not match final group when one group has a match

Tags: php, regex

I have data I need to split up in the following format:

```
22Dec17 DEB ACME 16.27
22Dec17 DEB BIG CO STORE 50.33
123353443
22Dec17 FEE CHARGE NAME 39.91 DR
123434454
22Dec17 DEB NAMENAME 12.91 123.23
22Dec17 DEB NAME 6 91
```

In the above example, the first two lines of data would be:

```
22Dec17, DEB, ACME, 16.27,
22Dec17, DEB, BIG CO STORE, 50.33, 123353443
22Dec17, FEE, CHARGE NAME, 39.91, 123434454
22Dec17, DEB, NAMENAME, 12.91,
22Dec17, DEB, NAME, 6 91,
```

I am using the following regex which mostly works:

```
([0-9]{1,2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2}) ([A-Z]{2,3}) ([A-Za-z.,\/& ]*) ?([0-9.]{1,8}[\. ][0-9.]{2})? ?(?:[0-9.]{1,8}[\. ][0-9.]{2})?\n?(?![0-9]{1,2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2})([0-9A-Z-\/ .]*)
```

The problem comes when there is a number in the name, like so:

```
27Dec15 DEB TESCO UPT 123 34.90
```

This creates the regex result:

```
27Dec15, DEB, TESCO UPT, 123 34, .97
```

How can I make this number only match when it is part of last two values? When it is in the format `12 34` or `12.34` only, and know that in `123 34.90` is does not consider `123 34` and `.90` parts of that match?

One way would be to force the \n char to be required. I have it optional for now, as otherwise it prevents all matches. Could it be part of the lookahead?

Is the part of the regex that checks if the next line does not contain a date correct? >

```
\n?(?![0-9]{1,2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2})([0-9A-Z-\/ .]*)
```

Comment: So what you want is `27Dec15, DEB, TESCO UPT, 123 34.90`?

Comment: I either want `27Dec15, DEB, TESCO UPT 123, 34.90` or to simply discard the 123 and return as `27Dec15, DEB, TESCO UPT, 34.90`. The point it, the 123 is part of the NAME column, only the 34.90 is for that column...

Comment: and you have the same problem with `22Dec17 DEB NAMENAME 12.91 123.23` in first example?

Comment: Try `^(\w+)(\h+[A-Z]{3})(.*?)(\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+[\h\w]*(?:\h*\R\s*(\w+)$)?+`. See live here https://regex101.com/r/8qNIHw/1

Comment: I would say use this [\(?m\)^\(\d{1,2}\w{2,4}\d{1,2}\)\[ \]+\(\w{3}\)\[ \]+\(.*?\)\[ \]+\(\d+\.\d+\)\(?:.*?\r?\n\(\d{9}\)\)?](https://regex101.com/r/mDraYA/1) but, you are not clear about the name field and the one that comes after it. I don't think you have a clear understanding. So, it doesn't make sense to start guessing at this point.

Comment: My turn: https://regex101.com/r/yjD2fy/1 (use a greedy subpattern for the name part).

Comment: This is a problem `When it is in the format 12 34 or 12.34 only` where `6 91` is what, part of _name_ or is it _number_ ?

Comment: Yes, the main problem is numbers at the end that is still unclear.

Comment: @sln What are you saying is unclear? Unfortunately your solution fails to extract the number when it is stored without a . and only as 6 91, as in the last example. Otherwise some interesting ideas.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Unfortunately this does not work. It groups the numbers with the name in the last example, returning `NAME 6` and `91` instead of `NAME` and `6 91`

Comment: Since there's no rule (at least in your question) to make the difference between a name that ends with digits and a name followed by a digit, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

`/(\d{0,2}[a-z]{3}\d{0,2})\s([^.]+)\s([\d.]+)[\n]?(\d+\s)?/gi`

This regex should get what you're after, demo in the code example. You'll just have to sanitize out the newlines later.
Breakdown:

- `(\d{0,2}[a-z]{3}\d{0,2})\s` match the date block, followed by a space
- `([^.]+)\s` Get the company name, so any character that isn't `.`, followed by a mandatory space
- `([\d.]+)` Get the cost
- `[\n]?(\d+\s)?` Optionally grab that extra line of digits, if it exists

```js
var teststrs = `22Dec17 DEB ACME 16.27
22Dec17 DEB BIG CO STORE 50.33
123353443
22Dec17 FEE CHARGE NAME 39.91 DR
123434454
22Dec17 DEB NAMENAME 12.91 123.23
22Dec17 DEB NAME 6 91`

var rgx = /(\d{0,2}[a-z]{3}\d{0,2})\s([^.]+)\s([\d.]+)[\n]?(\d+\s)?/gi

console.log(teststrs.match(rgx))
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this returns no matches.

Comment: Not sure why that would be the case, works fine for me, including right in the post if you run the code snippet. Could possibly be something in there that php interprets differently I suppose